# RGB color permutation

Tags: c++, opengl, permutation

I will be using color picking in my `openGL` app. I want to assign a unique color code to each object when it is created. My problem is how to have the permutation of `RGB` color values.

What I'm trying to have is a functions that returns a unique `RGB` color for every call so I could assign it to the object. For example, the first call will return a `RGB` color `(1, 0, 0)`, the next will have `(2, 0, 0)` and so on until it will return `(255, 255, 255)`.

So my problem is how to implement the function. I think the idea is to use permutation but I don't have the idea how to start. Is there a already implemented function of permutation in c++?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice, that RGB values are simply three bytes. You can just use simple int value and iterate from 1 (0x000001) through 16777215 (0xffffff). RGB values can be retreived by the following formulas:

```
unsigned char R = color % 256;
unsigned char G = (color / 256) % 256;
unsigned char B = (color / 65536) % 256;
```

or

```
unsigned char R = (color & 0xff);
unsigned char G = (color & 0xff00) >> 8;
unsigned char B = (color & 0xff0000) >> 16;
```

Comment: And the second formula, if not optimized by the compiler, is much, much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
colour function()
{
 static int r=-1,g=0,b=0 ;
 r++;
 if(r == 256)
 {
     r=0;
     g++
     if(g == 256)
     {
       g=0;
       b++;
     }
 }

 if(r == 255 && g==255 && b==255)
 r=g=b=0;

  // return colour form by r,g and b combination

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use:

```
rgbArray[255][3];
for (int r = 0; r < 255; ++r)
  rgbArray[r][0] = r;

numSwaps = 100;
for (int i = 0; i < numSwaps; ++i)
{
 a = rand()%255;
 b = rand()%255;
 swap(rgbArray[a], rgbArray[b]);
}
```

of course you can extend it to hold all variation of RGB colour and then randomize it...

Comment: I don't see a requirement for randomization. "Permutation" sounds pretty straight-forward to me.